# how to fetch a Jade file without double quotes

Tags: javascript, fetch, pug

- I want to use jade file in fetch.
- When writing a jade file, double
  quotation marks are inserted and the browser recognizes it as text.
- If I use 'home.html ' instead of 'home.jade', it works.

**view.jade**

```
doctype html
    html
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    style
        include view.css
    script
        include ../fetch/fetch.js
body
    header

    section
        nav

        main(id='view')
```

**home.jade**

```
div(id='main_image')
    input(type='image' class='leftbtn' src='/leftbtn.png')
    input(type='image' class='rightbtn' src='/rightbtn.png')    
p(class='main_p') sth
div(class='wrap_item')
```

**fetch.js**

```
fetch('home.jade').then((res)=>{
    res.text().then((text)=>{
        document.querySelector('#view').innerHTML = text;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jade code cannot be understood by the browser, that's why it is converted to HTML. You should fetch the home.html, since that's the one the browser can actually understand.